# Correct way to have an input of type submit and avoid spam-bots?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I used to have a form which submit button was just a div, like this:

```
<div class='submit-form'>Submit</div>
```

However, that didn't let my users to submit the form when pressing the enter key, so I added the following

```
<div class='submit-form'>Submit</div>
<input type='submit'>
```

A submit button, that I hide with CSS, so it's transparent to the user, but it's still functional.

What has happened since I added that is that I have gotten several spam submissions. So, my question is:

- Should I remove the input of type submit and somehow add a jQuery listener for the enter key in the form?

OR

- Should I add some kind of anti spam security?

Comment: The second option would be more effective and accessible.

Comment: Either is acceptable based on what you need. However, an event listener might not be interpreted correctly by a screen reader. If meeting accessibility guidelines for your disabled users is important to you, I would consider the second option.

Comment: You do realize that a spam bot doesn't even need to load your page to submit?

Comment: Erik Philips, so what do you suggest with that comment? I haven't had any kind of spammers until I added the <input type='submit'> in my form.

Comment: Why do you think it's spam? May be it's accidental hit of "enter"? Bots do not use buttons.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Do you have a problem with spam bots  (or are you assuming you are)?  Why do you think adding a button to the page will increase it?  This questions smells of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).

Comment: @Erik Philips, I am assuming that bots understand that if a form have an input of type 'submit', they can submit the form. Otherwise, how they will know which non-submit div they have to press?

Comment: Why not add CAPTCHA to your form to deter spam submissions instead?

Comment: It seems like your REAL question is, how do I allow users to use the enter key to submit, but prevent spambots from using the site.  And to me, those are two completely independent questions.  However this question is still relevant and minimally explained (so I don't see a reason to vote close it yet).

Comment: @HommerSmith bots do not click buttons. They see `<form>` in code and just know where to send data.

Comment: It's like my grandma always said, bots don't use buttons, kiddo, they just look for the `action` attribute on the form element. Silly old bird.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use standard html elements in forms, so you can have graceful degradation.
A form without a submit button can cause you more than one trouble (accessibility, javascript enabled in browser, etc...).
This is a general good rule.

Then you can implement a standard (do not reinvent the wheel!), *accessible* anti spam feature in your form, such as [recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha).